# Unable to install stacks from Kforge

Tags: ros, svn, kforge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sorry for the newbie question, but this does not appear to be covered in the StackInstallation tutorial or any other documentation I can find.  When I attempt to install the pr2_mechanism_model (or any other stack whose repository is on kforge), I get the following error:

% svn co https://kforge.ros.org/pr2mechanism/hg/file/6d505613a901/pr2_mechanism_model pr2_mechanism_model
svn: The OPTIONS response did not include the requested activity-collection-set; this often means that the URL is not WebDAV-enabled

Any assistance would be appreciated.
Thanks,
Paul.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11165/unable-to-install-stacks-from-kforge/) by [Paul0nc](https://answers.ros.org/users/1067/paul0nc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 271 on 2011-09-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That stack is using Mercurial, not Subversion.

```
$ roslocate info pr2_mechanism
- hg:
    local-name: pr2_mechanism
    uri: https://kforge.ros.org/pr2mechanism/hg
```

Try something like:

```
$ hg clone https://kforge.ros.org/pr2mechanism/hg pr2_mechanism
```

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-09-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5